# How to share URL using Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sharing

I'm developing an app for my local newspaper. When you press the "`Share`" button, I want the standard iOS share interface to appear allowing users to share the URL of an article with Facebook, Twitter, etc. I'm trying to use the `UIActivityViewController`, and while it appears, it's not giving me all of the options.

Here's the code I use:

```
NSObject[] activitiesItems = { 
                                new NSString(post.Title),
                                new NSUrl(post.URL)
                             };

var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(activitiesItems, null);
PresentViewController(activityController, true, null);
```

When the UI opens, this is all I see (no Twitter or Facebook): [image: sharing options in my app]

This is in comparison to what I see when I share a page from Safari, which has the Facebook and Twitter options, along with a variety of others: [image: sharing options in Safari]

What do I have to change in my code to allow more of these options to appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your code is fine

2) On your iOS Simulator go to the Setting and login to Twitter and/or FaceBook accounts and retest your app.

iOS Simulator Setting (botton off screen):

[image]

Here is my Simulator view with me logged into Twitter but not Facebook using the same code you posted:

[image]

3) Safari is a using a custom `ViewController` to display what you are seeing... If you actually try to share a link via that Twitter button you will be force to login..

4) Use an actual device for complete testing of all the possible sharing applications installed.

Answer (score 1):

Those options are only supposed to show when you are logged in to an account in the Settings app for FB and Twitter. They are hidden if not.

However that doesn't really explain why they show up in Safari.

Perhaps including the `NSString` for `post.Title` in the items array is causing it to exclude some sharing options.